# android- Gradle: An issue occurred configuring root project android studio

Tags: android

I migrated from eclipse to android studio. I've create a new project and I want to run it on genymotion. When I press run icon, it begins to compile and give me this error :

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Khabar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         :Khabardar:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-1.1.0.pom'.
         > d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net
```

This is some parts of my build.gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.ir.khabar"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle in root :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.ir.khabar"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources.jar')
}
```

Could you help me? my  gradle version is gradle-2.2.1-all

Comment: Post the build.gradle in root folder.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for reply ,I edit my answer and add build.gradle in root folder

Comment: what do you have "buildscript" section?

Comment: @mohamadbagheri are you sure about your file in root folder?

Comment: any update guys?

Comment: I am also getting the same exception, searched online but none worked.Please help me on this MyQuestion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182192/updated-androidstudio3-5-3-not-building-android-project-caused-by-org-gradle

Answer (score 16):

For me, the solution was to add the http url for jcenter, instead of https:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should i add that ? the file build.gradle in my project ?

Comment: Mine is in the Project build.gradle file.

Comment: [Pertinent reading](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9giiv7/psa_jcenter_bintray_repo_certificate/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Al's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29852744/2999762) answer, I also had to put the url inside `allprojects`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I was able to fix it by replacing **ibm-java80-jdk** & **ibm-java80-jre** with **openjdk**. Also, I did update my DNS to cloudflare DNS. But I don't think it had anything to do with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

add google() in your gradle inside the repositories section will solve your problem..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```