# Gradle exception

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-gradle-plugin

how can i fix this ??

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>   'Procode1'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
> >          Required by:
> >              :Procode1:unspecified
> >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-1.1.0.pom'.
> >     jcenter.bintray.com
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 29.267 secs
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I changed proxyPort to 8080 and used jcenter instead of Maven. But i had to apply expeption to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. This is what i have in my gradle.build for build script and allprojects

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}


 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
      }
    }
```

[android- Gradle: An issue occurred configuring root project android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715890/android-gradle-an-issue-occurred-configuring-root-project-android-studio)

Comment: thank you :) but where to paste this code exactly ??

Comment: restart android studio

Comment: after restarting and alot of time in downloading for packages from gradle before running the build has been done already .. giving me that  :     To run a build, run gradle <task> ...
To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks
To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 38.757 secs
Process finished with exit code 0
To run a build, run gradle <task> ...
To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks
To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 38.757 secs
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: but no effect in the emulator